# check if glyph is rendered "correctly"

Tags: unicode, tcl, font-awesome, tk-toolkit, glyph

I'm writing a tcl/tk application, where i would like to use font-awesome icons.

In principal, this works nicely: just display some string/label with the correct unicode char, and if the proper fonts are installed, it will render)

Now, on my dev machine i have font-awesome installed as an ordinary machine.
I cannot expect that on the deployment machines.

So I would like to find out, whether the system can render a given character, or whether it just uses a *glyph-not-found* placeholder. In the latter case, i would just fallback to some less-nice representation...

(I don't want my users to have to answer a question like "does this string look correct?")

E.g. the symbol "" (`&#xf16c;`) displays as the stackoverflow-icon in my application. in my browser it is rendered as a *glyph-not-found*.

So, is there a way to find out programmatically, if any of the (used) system fonts provides the glyph for a given character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't; it's outright missing functionality. The closest you can get is to get the actual font info for a character — requires 8.6 I think — or to measure its width, but that doesn't really help:

```
% font actual TkFixedFont
-family Monaco -size 11 -weight normal -slant roman -underline 0 -overstrike 0
% font actual TkFixedFont \uf16c
-family Monaco -size 11 -weight normal -slant roman -underline 0 -overstrike 0
% font measure TkFixedFont \uf16c
14
```

(The character renders as the glyph-not-found symbol on this system with that font.)